# Correct way to do this in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-old-router

So should the click action goto a method on the router say 'showPropertyPanel' and that puts the router in a showProperties state on this page show route?
Then setup the properties outlet.

Is this correct?
Problem is I don’t want the route to change from /pages/1234  to /pages/1234/showproperties

Is this the correct way to do this now all actions through the router to change state?  Can you have states with and without routes mixed in together?

Before I would just fire an event on the PageView to create the Properties Panel and show it etc.

Please can someone give me some help on this as I am sure I am not the only on struggling with this at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler, on the state, does not have to go to a new state to show the panel.  It can, but it doesn't have to.  It's sort of an architectural decision on how to handle such things.  If complicated things can happen when the panel is up, you might want a new state, to handle all the events that can originate from the Panel.

On the other hand,  you can do what you were doing before, but do it in the router instead of directly on the view.

With respect to the route issue, can't you just do

`route: "/",`

on the panel state to keep it the same as it was before?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Any chance you could show me in code how this can be handled on the router while not changing state ?  Thanks a lot.  Rick